# Is a specific voltage required for a specific frequency (in processors)?

Tags: voltage, frequency

I read in a [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6820976/) about latency in dynamic voltage and frequency scaling, that the voltage has to "support" the frequency. According to this paper, if the frequency is too high for the voltage it causes a "dangerous state" (I love how specific they are).

Can somebody please explain what the relationship is? Or point me in the right direction? Also, an equation would be great.

My background is in computers and my understanding about electrical stuff very limited. I already looked online and from what I found, there does not seem to be a relationship. Maybe I'm misunderstanding it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The access to the paper is limited. So without looking at it I would guess it is talking about some very specific system.

Comment: For a specific processor, yes.

Comment: In general, the reachable clock speed of a processor depends to some extent on the voltage, but is not a 1 to 1 relationship.  You can't map a particular voltage to a specific frequency.  You also can't get too carried away.  Raise the voltage a bit and your processor might run a little better at a higher speed.  Raise the voltage too much, and the processor will never run again.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks i never thought about that. i will look further into this.

the system is the intel scc: https://www.intel.cn/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technology-briefs/intel-labs-single-chip-platform-overview-paper.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really complicated, but rather complex. Roughly speaking, the speed (running frequency) of a processor depends on switching speed of logic gates. The switching speed, in turn, depends on driving strength of transistor pairs, which must drive connected nets. The nets have certain capacitance, so with the higher voltage rail the voltage (switching) threshold gets reached faster (since transistor's thresholds are fixed in a particular manufacturing process), so the gate delay is smaller, and pipelines can run faster.

However, with higher switching voltage the gate would dissipate more (as a function of V^^2), so the die can overheat, which has opposite effect, it slows the switching speed down, and also can destroy the logic unit, say by drastically increase electromigration rate. This imposes upper limit on voltage-speed relationship.

In the idea of dynamic "scaling", some blocks of CPU (like cache/memory controller) can be configured on fly to run faster, which need higher voltage. So the idea is that every important logic block has an internal LDO power sujpply, and a variable clock control unit. If there is a demand for faster execution of this unit, an auxiliary processor called "PMU", Power Management Unit, would raise the corresponding voltage, then increase its running clock. When demand goes down, the PMU drops the clock first, then reduces the voltage. And PMU microcode monitors temperature of blocks as well.

In short, for every reasonable voltage level there is certain maximum clock rate when the logic can operate without timing errors. Lower clock rate is usually okay, but one can optimize the block for running at lower voltage, which has power saving advantages (like less leakage). On bottom end, if the voltage is set too low, the operating frequency can be zero, so the logic can only maintain flip-flop states, but can't switch.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a specific voltage required for a specific frequency (in processors)?

As asked the answer is no. There is no general law or mechanism that dictates you need voltage V to use frequency F.

> I read in a paper about latency in dynamic voltage and frequency scaling, that the voltage has to "support" the frequency. According to this paper, if the frequency is too high for the voltage it causes a "dangerous state" (I love how specific they are).

Now this is a different matter. For any specific processor, or technology, the speed at which the gates, transistors, within the device can switch from a logic low level to a logic high level, or vica-versa, has a finite maximum. The time taken is referred to as the rise-time and the fall-time and is independent of the frequency of the signal.

[image]

As such, you can see that as the frequency increases the flat high and low points reduce in width relative to the transitions. If you increase the frequency too far the high and low levels are NEVER reached and the device will no longer operate.

Further, while switching, considerable power is consumed during those transitions compared to very little power to hold the level. So again, as the frequency approaches the rise and fall times the power consumed, and heat generated, in the device climbs and can cause the device to melt down.

Reducing the voltage level helps here. Looking at the pulse above you can see that by halving the voltage the rise and fall times are also reduced by about half. That gives you the ability to crank up the clock rate further than you could with the original voltage.

**However:** There is also a cost in reducing the operating voltage. When you reduce the voltage you also end up reducing the signal to noise ratio. That is, and as an extreme example, a 5V CPU may not mind 1V of noise, but a 1.8V CPU will definitely hate it. As such there is a trade off here.

Hybrid devices also exist. Many modern processors actually use an internal voltage that is much less than the applied voltage to accommodate faster switching while level translating to the external pins.